# I want to call a specific variable by referencing the content of another variable

Tags: vba, loops, variables, for-loop, indexing

Look at this first:

```
Dim Item1 As String
Dim Item2 As String
Dim Item3 As String
Dim Item4 As String
Dim Item5 As String

'Add text to these strings within the script
```

Basically, I have a list of variables that use a simple number to keep them separated.

I'm printing these variables into a userform, as well as applying some formats to those forms.  The user forms also have the same numbers in them.

My code in the userform would look something like this.

```
Form1.Caption = Item1
Form1.BackColor = 'Condition based on content of Item1
Label1.Width = 'Condition based on content of Item1
Form2.Caption = Item2
Form2.BackColor = 'Condition based on content of Item1
Label2.Width = = 'Condition based on content of Item1

'...and so on and so forth...
```

I'm *actually* working with 10 variables and have some case statements to handle the conditions referenced above, so the code is getting rather lengthy.

I'd like to use a simple:

```
for i = 1 to 5
```

And then *something* in the userform that might look like:

```
Form{i}.Caption = Item{i}
Form{i}.BackColor = 'Condition based on content of Item{i}
Label{i}.Width = 'Condition based on content of Item{i}
```

Does this make sense?  The program "AutoHotKey" which I used for some basic PC macros has this feature - the format if I recall is simply

```
form%_i
```

But obviously that's AHK and this is VBA!!

I don't know if it can even be accomplished, but I frequently have this problem and it'd be nice to get some resolution...

Comment: You should be able to use & as in form & 1 to concatenate. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Is there any reason that you are avoiding something like  `Dim Items(1 to 10) As String`?

Comment: John - that actually is what I've done - I have an array of collections with the data in it that I want to output into fields of a user form.  However, I can't (that I know of) place user form fields into an array.

Comment: Cptn_Hammer - I tried your technique but unfortunately it doesn't work.  When I type:
`Form&i.Caption`
(where "i" is simply an integer dimensioned above)
VBA automatically changes it to
`Form& i.Caption`
However when I attempt to run the code, I get:
"Compile error: Invalid Qualifier"

Comment: `Form1` has target `Label1`, why does `Form2` has target `Label2`, but not `Label1`? What is the purpose of naming labels such way?

Comment: omegastripes - I don't have a Form2 - I have FormName.Label1 through FormName.Label5.  Instead of calling out Label1 through Label 5 and assigning the contents of array[1] through array[5], I want to assign FormX to Array[X] using a FOR statement.

Answer (score 1):

For controls you can use something like:

`myForm.Controls("Label" & i).Width`

For referencing a userform see: http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=63433

```
Dim frm As Object

On Error Resume Next
Set frm = UserForms.Add("UserForm" & 1)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not frm Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print "Got form: " & frm.Caption
Else
    Debug.Print "No form with that name!"
End If
```

Comment: YOU WIN!!!  That worked perfectly.  It doesn't solve every instance of this problem I've encountered, but it works for this one!  Thanks.